# How to send mail to users through php

Tags: php, email

I have contact form on my website and works fine. I receive the mails as well.

My website is [this](http://peterbousaada.cf), and here is the [contact form](http://peterbousaada.cf/contact.html)

The only issue that I'm facing is I receive the mails easily, but I'm not able to send the revert mails to the users.
I tried the php mail() function as well.

Here is my contact form page
'contact.html' :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="master.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css">
<title>welcome to peter's official website</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "header">
    <div class="menu">
    <a  href="index.html">
    <div class="menuitem">Home
    </div>
    </a>
    <font size="5px"    color="white">|</font>
    <a  href="peter.html">
    <div class="menuitem">About me 
    </div>
    </a>
    <font size="5px"    color="white">|</font>
    <a href="contact.html">
    <div class="menuitem">Contact Me
    </div>
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container">
<h1 class="middle-text">Contact Me</h1>
<form id="contact-form" action="mail.php" method="post">
<div>
<label>
    <span>First Name<font color="red" size="4px">*</font> :</span></br>
    <input name="fname" type="text" Placeholder="Your First Name" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
</label>
</div>
<div>
<label>
    <span>Last Name<font color="red" size="4px">*</font> :</span></br>
    <input name="lname" type="text" Placeholder="Your Last Name" tabindex="2" required>
</label>
</div>
<div>
<label>
    <span>E-mail<font color="red" size="4px">*</font> :</span></br>
    <input name="email" type="email" Placeholder="Your E-mail" tabindex="3" required>
</label>
</div>
<div>
<label>
    <span>subject<font color="red" size="4px">*</font> :</span></br>
    <input name="subject" type="text" Placeholder="Email subject" tabindex="4" required>
</label>
</div>
<div>
<label>
    <span>Message<font color="red" size="4px">*</font> :</span></br>
    <textarea name="message" type="text" placeholder="Your Message" tabindex="5" required></textarea>
</label>
</div>
<div>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit">Send Email</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<script src="validation-script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is 'mail.php' :

```
<?php
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent="From:\n$fname $lname\n\nSubject:\n$subject\n\nMessage:\n$message \n\nEmail:\n$email";
$recipient = "contact@peterbousaada.cf";
mail($recipient,$subject, $formcontent) or header("Location:http://peterbousaada.cf/error.html");
$subject = "thank you";
$formcontent = "we have recieved your email, and we will get back to you as soon as possible";
$recipient = $email;
mail($recipient,$subject,$formcontent) or header("Location:http://peterbousaada.cf/error.html");
header("Location:http://peterbousaada.cf/thankyou.html");
?>  
enter code here
```

just to be clear, I tried renaming the variables in second mail() function from
**$recipient,$subject,$formcontent**
to
**$email,$next-sub,$next-msg**

Please take in consideration that I'm very new to php, so try to explain your answers thoroughly.
Thanks in advance

Comment: `$recipient = "$email";` that makes the email address the string "$email" so just drop the quotes

Comment: As many will quote here... Use PHPMailer... It will save you so many headaches.. Dont get me wrong i write some packages with just mail... but it takes alot more time to account for everything including a simple img.

Comment: i do not want to use a mailer, i want to get to know php better

Comment: thank you @Dagon i tried it but didnt work

Comment: update above with the changes you made

Comment: looks valid, make sure you test a couple of diffirent email addresses

Comment: Is mail() returns false?

Answer (score -2):

Change your 'mail.php' file to this, I hope it works.

```
 <?php
        $fname = $_POST['fname'];
        $lname = $_POST['lname'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $formcontent="From:\n$fname $lname\n\nSubject:\n$subject\n\nMessage:\n$message \n\nEmail:\n$email";

        $recipient = "contact@peterbousaada.cf";


    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: <contact@peterbousaada.cf>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: abc@example.com' . "\r\n";

    $mail=mail($email,$subject,$message,$headers);
    if($mail!=false)
    {
      echo "mail sent";
    }
    else
    {
      echo "mail not sent";
    }
```